# Passing GPS coordinates from my iPhone to a web service and displaying the GPS coordinates on a Map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services

I am trying to create an App which takes the GPS co-ordinates of my iPhone and displays my current position on the Map.

I have got the GPS co-ordinates from my iPhone using LocateMe Sample code, so now that is not a problem for me.

But I don't know how to send my GPS co-ordinates from my iPhone to a web service and display the GPS co-ordinates on a Map. It would be nice if you guys could help me out with this issue.

Comment: On which web service you want to send GPS coordinate ?

Comment: To say the truth I don't know. I want to display my GPS co-ordinates on a Map. So should I create a Web Service of my own to display the GPS co-ordinates on a Map or is there already a Web Service which can do that. I have got GPS co-ordinates but I am totally blank about what to do next!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to use the nsurlconnection class as follows (you'll just need to set the requestWithUrl parameter in the NSURLRequest which the web-service specific url):

```
-(void)getLocationsFromWebService {
    NSLog(@"in getLocationsFromWebService");


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:TRUE];


    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.locationsURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:100.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    self.requestType = @"GET";
    if (theConnection) {
        _responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain ];
    } else {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:FALSE];
    }
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:FALSE]; 
    NSLog(@"in mapviewcontroller");
    NSLog(@"Error connecting - %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    [connection release];
    [_responseData release];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSInteger statusCode = [HTTPResponse statusCode];

    if (404 == statusCode || 500 == statusCode) {
        //[self.controller setTitle:@"Error Getting Parking Spot ....."];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:FALSE];

        [connection cancel];
        NSLog(@"Server Error - %@", [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:statusCode]);
    } else {
        if ([self.requestType isEqualToString:@"GET"])
            [_responseData setLength:0];
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if ([self.requestType isEqualToString:@"GET"])
        [_responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    if ([self.requestType isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
        [self parseLocations:_responseData];
        [_responseData release];
    }
    [connection release];

}
```

Comment: thank you for your immediate response. As I mentioned before I want to display my GPS co-ordinates on a Map. To do that should I create a Web Service of my own or is there already a web service which can take my GPS co-ordinates and display it on a Map. I have my GPS co-ordinates in my hand It would be really of great help if you could give me some idea how to proceed from here afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to create web services for just to display your current location on Map. You just need to implement corelocation and Mapkit framework in order to achieve your functionality. As you said you got your GPS co-ordinates so you just need to implement mapkit and set your current location as user location. Map kit does it automatically so you need not to do anything for that. Just search for mapkit example and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to:

Use NRURLRequest in order to pass the latitude/longitude (using a POST method for example) to a PHP page.

Create that PHP scipt in order to read that parameters and then build location like this:
  location  => NAME, lat=>LATITUDE ,lon =>LONGITUDE 
and use a jsonphp method to build that in json format.

in iphone, now you just receive this information using NSURLRequest and parse the json. send the  result of parse to the mapkit.