# Building a web server app that tracks android phones using GPS

Tags: android, gps, web

I have already android app that is capable of getting GPS data. Now I want the app to send the GPS co=ordinates to a web server. Say, I have an app with Google Map embedded, running on my desktop PC. Now I want this application to show the location on Google Map by obtaining the GPS data from the web server. Being an amateur, I don't know much about web APIs. So, could anyone direct me.  I need a good start.

This one's seems similar [Passing GPS coordinates from my iPhone to a web service and displaying the GPS coordinates on a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693704/passing-gps-coordinates-from-my-iphone-to-a-web-service-and-displaying-the-gps-c)

But I need to know the differences in Android platform

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the lat/long to a web server and use google API to link it to maps - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

or use HTML5 Geo-location then pass the lat/long onto maps again -

http://html5demos.com/geo

Comment: Thanks. Is this all the code required http://html5demos.com/geo#view-source. I didn't knew this was this simple. BTW, does this require any API key or something. I think for using google map api, one need to get a key.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Everything you need to know to start using Google API. It is pretty simple.

Vote up please for answer :)